# How to call a form.py in another application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model named NameModel in my app named Customer. I wanna reuse that model's one of the choices in my another app's model or forms.py. How can I do that. Following is the code of my form in Customer app. 
`GENDERCHOICES = (
        ( "", ("---")),
        (6, ("Male")),
        (7, ("Female")),
        (8, ("Notknown")),
    )`
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that GENDERCHOICES is either a class member of NameModel or a tuple defined at your Customer app models.py

just import it and use it as you normally would, in your models.py file:

```
from Customer.models import NameModel

ExampleModel(models.Model):
   type = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=NameModel.GENDERCHOICES)
```

or ...

```
from Customer.models import GENDERCHOICES

ExampleModel(models.Model):
   type = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDERCHOICES)
```

if your tuple is not defined inside the NameModel class.

Cheers.

**EDIT**

to edit a tuple you have to convert it to a list append to it and then convert back to a tuple:

```
l = list(GENDERCHOICES)
l.append(((9,("Something else")))
GENDERCHOICES_EXTRA = tuple(l)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Wow thats great. What if I want to add a new gender type in to the choices in my new model(resuing the customer  form)?

Comment: Remember that GENDERCHOICES is a tuple: a tupple is an immutable sequence type unlike a list you can't change a tuple. If you want to add new choices to your new model you have to create a new tuple, a way to do this is convert GENDERCHOICES to a list, append your new choice and then convert back to a tupple.

Comment: Bro the problem is the first model is my Boss's model. He wont make nay changes there. Only possible part is my side. Is there any way I can add a new field after I call the choices from customer table?

Comment: I will edit my answer with some code that might help you, and please remember to  [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)